# Can we use Managed Coherence Servers (MCS) feature with single Weblogic cluster to deploy application and coherence GAR?

Tags: oracle, caching, weblogic12c, oracle-coherence

We have a Weblogic cluster with set of managed servers where we have already deployed our enterprise application which heavily involved in database transactions. Recently we have migrated to Weblogic 12c and we have a proposal in pipeline to use Oracle Coherence to enable a caching layer so that we can improve application performance.

After doing a research we found that Managed Coherence Servers (MCS) feature in WLS 12c supported by creating additional storage enabled cluster which we can be used to deploy the GAR.

However increasing memeory in the production set up in costly to create a new cluster hence before proposing it **I want to know whether Oracle Coherence feature can be used without creating a new cluster but without compromising MCS features?**

Comment: Could you clarify the question a little? Do you want to create a caching layer without explicitly creating storage nodes for coherence caches ? When you say increasing memory in production is a challenge, does it mean you have limited RAM memory in production environment (because you need to allocate some space to coherence caches where it will store/cache the data for you).

Comment: Thanks you very much for your prompt response. > Creating a new cluster for multiple nodes requires a considerable RAM space and getting this infrastructure sorted out is bit difficult. I'm thinking of not going for creating a new cluster but deploy the GAR if it is possible to deploy in the same cluster as in application with storage enabled feature. Point is I believe creating a new cluster with multiple nodes requires more memory compare to allow space for coherence cache storage. of course relative to application requirements. More importantly Is above theoretically possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can create Oracle Coherence caches in the same cluster where application EAR is deployed. Follow this link on how to create the caches [Pack GAR with Application EAR](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLCOH/create-application.htm#WLCOH722)

**But it always make sense to have your caching layer separate from your application layer**. As caches also use the Heap Memory to store/cache objects. When your application and the cache are deployed in the same server (same JVM), they will have to share the heap space among themselves. And as far as i know, there is no clear way to define separate zones in heap memory for different application running on same JVM.

Hence there is a high probability for any of the application to consume more heap and make the other to starve and ultimately causing Out of Memory exceptions. Plus capacity planning for Coherence caches will also be a nightmare as you have to consider the memory consumed by the application too.

Comment: Convincing Answer @Prabal. Thank you very much!